# Presenting ViewController Z-Index Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, model-view-controller, ios8

So my app is laid out in the following format.

There is a rootVC on the Window. Then i have another viewController (lets call it PlayerVC), which has 2 views, and i've added the second view as a subview to the window. Now i am trying to present a UIAlertController (Presenting it from the PlayerVC) on top of it, but it gets hidden beneath the topmost view.

[image]

As can be seen in the image, when i add the alert, the dark shaded view gets added beneath the topmost view and the small actionsheet can be seen at the bottom. I have no idea how to get it to show on top =S

Comment: Why have you added the second view as a subview to the window? I'm assuming this is the one the alertView is drawing underneath?

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin the reason i am doing that is, i am trying to build a music player similar to Spotify's iOS App. So the RootVC is all the normal flow of the app, and the playerVC has two views, one is a miniPlayer that is shown at the bottom of the screen at all times (added as a subview to the window) and when that is tapped, playerVC's second view gets added to the the window which is a full screen player. Now i am unable to show a alert on top of this full screen player.

Comment: This is a very bad idea. I would recommend having a viewController as the root and adding childViewControllers to it and not adding anything to the window. I have previously made a root vc with a horizontal scrolling scrollview with child viewControllers added to it and paging enabled. Then you would be able to add the mini player to the root vc instead of the window

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin alright, i shall give this approach a go. The reason i went with the window approach was, so the miniplayer would always stay on screen, even if a side menu was opened, which Spotify achieves somehow. Lets see if i can achieve this using the technique you've suggested =)

Comment: well if your using a side nav, there will already be a root vc adding the other vc's as child vc's of it. Thats how it will slide the in / out. You can add it here above everything else

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin and yes, you were correct! it worked! I added the PlayerVC as a childVC to the rootVC. Thank You so much! =D

Comment: Ok I added the above to an answer since it solved the issue. Please accept it so that others facing the same issue will see what solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you already have a root viewController that you can use instead of the window.

You are using a sideNav which adds the rest of your screens to itself in order to display them and animate them.

If you add your player as a child of the root sidenav vc, it will be able to display over all the other controls on the screen, without using the window.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you against adding views directly to the window.

I have a similar setup to what you are doing in an app I'm currently working on, and my solution was to have a RootViewController with two containers, one for content and one for the player.

You can add containers through Interface Builder, and link them to another ViewController.

If you are not using Interface Builder, you can add the player and content views as child view controllers on your rootViewController.

That way you'll avoid issues when presenting view controllers by other means.

Comment: If by containers you meant childVC's, then yes you are correct and it worked! Thank you so much! =D

Comment: Containers are the way to add childViewControllers through Interface Builder, but I'll edit my answer for people who do this through code.